# Running Script on container from host

Tags: bash

I've made a script to perform an automate update to PHP service in a container.
At some stage i check if the new PHP version is activated with the following commands:

```
echo ''| update-alternatives --config php | grep $version | grep auto | head -n 1 | tr -d ' \n\r\t '
```

the "echo" at the beginning canceling the interactive interaction from the 'update-alternatives' command.

the $version variable is an input from the user(OPTARG) and has a default value if not set.

when im trying to save the command output to a variable , the variable is always set to null after executing the command.
i've tried the following ways:

```
var=$(echo ''| update-alternatives --config php | grep $version | grep auto | head -n 1 | tr -d ' \n\r\t ')
```

and:

```
var=`echo ''| update-alternatives --config php | grep $version | grep auto | head -n 1 | tr -d ' \n\r\t '`
```

The result of the command when im not redirecting the output to a variable is:

```
0/usr/bin/php8.181automode
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the failed command piecemeal.

(Note: my system has only one version of php installed so substituting vi for the example below.)

The command

```
echo '' | update-alternatives --config vi | grep gtk3 | grep auto
```

reports

```
{*} 0            /usr/bin/vim.gtk3    50        auto mode
```

So ... I suggest that your coding doesn't take into account the format for reporting the choices.

Instead of the tr, use

```
awk '{ for( i=1 ; i < $NF ; i++){ if( index($i,"/") == 1 ){ print $i ; exit } ; } ; }'
```